# Can you add line breaks to the :after pseudo element?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I want to append a `<br />` to a particular class. Using the :after pseudo class simply displays `<br />` as text.

Is there a way to make this work?

It's internal for IE8 so browser issues aren't a problem. If I do

```
<span class="linebreakclass">cats are</span> brilliant
```

I want "brilliant" to appear on a new line.

Comment: See this questiosn: [Adding HTML entities using CSS content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content) Although based on other answers it sounds like even that won't work...

Comment: See: https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You won't be able to render HTML tags but you can set style like this:

```css
.needs-space:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    clear: both; /* if you need to break floating elements */
}
```

The main setting here is `display: block;` This will render *:after* content inside a `DIV`. And this pseudo element is supported by all latest browsers. Including IE. Saying this you should be aware of your users and their browsers.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. It's an internal software project and all computers are running IE8 so I don't mind using complex css :)

Answer (score 15):

You can use `\A` escape sequence, which will render as a newline:

```
.new-line:after {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  content: "\A";
}
```

This method was mentioned in the [CCS 2.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html) for the `content` property:

> Authors may include newlines in the generated content by writing the
>   `"\A"` escape sequence in one of the strings after the `'content'`
>   property. This inserted line break is still subject to the
>   [`'white-space'`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-white-space) property.

Answer (score 1):

It gets worse - the :after class doesn't even work in IE6 (and probably some other browsers too).

I think what you really want here is a margin on the bottom of the element, to provide spacing.

Simply

```
.myElement {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Edited for clarification - I don't think a margin will do that?

Comment: I see - my answer only applies to the first revision of the question

Answer (score 1):

You can either add a custom icon from your assets, by doing simply ..

```
 &:after {
    content: url('~content/icons/drop-down-arrow.png');
  }
```