# Insert anchor link in :after selector content

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

So I'm just trying to insert a link after some content but it just displays the literal string. How do I change this?

```
<p>Blah Blah Blah I'm some content</p>
```

CSS:

```
p:after {
    content: '- <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Learn More</a>'
}
```

which produces of course the text:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

Blah Blah Blah I'm some content - <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Learn More</a>
```

I expect the following output

> Blah Blah Blah I'm some content - [Learn More](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you use the :after pseudo element to add html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672879/can-you-use-the-after-pseudo-element-to-add-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need javaScript for this kind of things.

It can easily be done with jQuery. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/Rq42L/)**

HTML

```
<p id="p">Blah Blah Blah I'm some content</p>
```

jQuery

```
var plink ='- <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Learn More</a>';
$('#p').append(plink);
```