# CSS: content:"\00a0"

Tags: css

Today I came across a new CSS syntax that I have never seen before

```
content:"\00a0";
```

Checking it on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_gen_content.asp), it explains:

> Definition and Usage
>
> The content property is used with the :before and :after pseudo-elements, to insert generated content.

My question is, can you point out to me in real world example, how do we use this `content` property? And what does the `\00a0` mean in this case?

Comment: You can find more code here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/

Comment: [`NO-BREAK SPACE`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've used it before to implement styling text on a floated list

```css
#horz-list li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

#horz-list li:after {
  content: "\00a0-\00a0";
}

 #horz-list li:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<ul id="horz-list">
  <li>first item</li>
  <li>second item</li>
  <li>third item</li>
</ul>
```

That will produce something like

first item  - second item - third item

This keeps my markup semantic & I can introduce styling such a the dash via css.

Answer (score 61):

The `content` property is used to add content or even adding html entities. As for `\00a0`, it is hex code for a non-breaking space.

Resources:

**[More Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content)**
**[Javascript, CSS, and (X)HTML entities in numeric order](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/)**