# nbsp not working in CSS content tag

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding HTML entities using CSS content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content)

```
#sitenavmenu-content-menu li:before
{
    content:"|&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
```

I want to add a | and two spaces before each list item. However, for some reason it prints the word nbsp and not the space. Any ideas?

Comment: Sometimes the best selector is with "no pipe at begin", so `li:not(:first-child):before`

Answer (score 369, accepted):

This could be the answer you are looking for :

```
content: "|\00a0\00a0";
```

Comment: You forgot the pipe character:

content:"\007C\00a0\00a0";

Though just: content:"\007C"; and a bit of margin-right might be more scalable

Comment: `"\7C\a0\a0"` will also work.

Comment: Why do you need to escape the `|`?

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I used it in my similar situation...I had an id with a non-breaking-space in it: `<a id="Hello&nbsp;World">`. To target that in css I needed to use `#Hello\00a0World` and then it worked.

Comment: I suggest: `content: "\007c"; margin-right: 2ch;` because 2ch is twice the width of the current font's '0' character. See the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#ch), and [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ch-unit)

Comment: @Oriol, today most of web pages are UTF-8 and  the `\00`  is to a "safe UTF-8 representation".

Comment: @TWiStErRob , good question. You not need to escape, and it **is a good practice to express visible characters as it  in UTF-8**.  `content: "|\00a0\00a0";`

Comment: oops, see [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1412764/287948), the secure is with 3 zeros, `\0000a0`, to avoid parse problems when mixing content as `cotentent: "|\0000a0Break"` for "|  Break".

Comment: If you just need _&nbsp;_, then `content: "\a0"`

Comment: For a quad space, use `content: "\2001";`. For more types of whitespace, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

Answer (score -4):

Fixed it by copying and pasting the non-breaking space from character map into my code editor.

Comment: Works but I would not do it that way. Too easy to break.

Comment: This works as well