# CSS selector not working with [value="&nbsp"]

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, struts

I am trying to make the following selector work with my HTML:

```
input[type="submit"][value="&nbsp;"]:not(.unwantedIconClass)/*, thisIsAComment*/
```

It will not work unless I replace value with actual text (and have the same text in the HTML, of course).

I have tried `\007C\00a0\00a0` following advice from [nbsp not working in CSS content tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965229/nbsp-not-working-in-css-content-tag) but it does not seem to work either *and* makes Eclipse syntax coloring confused.

What I actually want is for the value to be invisible to the user but selectable using CSS. It does not matter what the value actually is.
This is because I do not have control about the input tag, only its value attribute.

Any suggestions ?

EDIT -- Since it is part of the problem, I will explain more:
The value of my value attribute is actually generated through a custom JSP tag, and that custom JSP tag is enclosed by a `layout:submit` attribute (Struts Layout).

```
<layout:submit 
    styleClass="tooCommonClass"
    reqCode="notAReliableIdentifierEither">
    <customTag:message key="keyToPropertyFile" />
</layout:submit>
```

Comment: `\007C\00a0\00a0` corresponds to | followed by *two* no-break spaces as given in the question, not just a single no-break space. That would be simply \00a0. Can't comment on the syntax coloring issue.

Comment: Unfortunately \00a0 does not work either :/
I think the JSP tag used has some responsibility in it, but not much I can do about it.

Comment: *If a graphical button is needed (a button with an image), then the `image` tag is more appropriate.* - http://www.jajakarta.org/struts/struts1.2/documentation/ja/target/userGuide/struts-html.html#submit.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the empty string for `value`.

```css
input[type="submit"][value=""] {
    background-color: orange;
}

input[type="submit"][value="_"] {
    background-color: purple;
    font-size: 0;
    color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="submit" value="_" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a behavior of the user agent or the behavior of the enclosing JSP tag, but I cannot put a blank "value" attribute to the submit tag because this will display "Submit" inside the button.
What I want is no text and an icon displayed thanks to CSS (if the selector worked).
I have to avoid modifying the HTML if ever possible.

Comment: Probably JSP.  I tested in Chrome, FF, and IE11 and it's fine.  You could use an arbitrary `value` and change `color` to `transparent` or `font-size` to `0` to hide the text.

Comment: font-size 0 I have read is unreliable, but thanks for the other suggestion, I will try it and post an update.