# Wordpress span width not changing after changing to block and adding &nbsp

Tags: html, css, wordpress

At the moment, I have a span on a wordpress website I'm working on that appears in a funny place by default for each of the portfolio entries.

It is easiest to illustrate with pictures.

**What I want to do:**

*The top two squares show how wordpress portfolio-type span is defaulting to and the bottom two squares are how I want to display the portfolio-type.*
[image]

Here's the code I'm attempting to use to fix this issue, followed by images that imitate the result. I have provided sources for my solution below the images:

```
/*Hard-code parent position relative to itself so that we can position its children absolutely across the board*/

  .tmb.tmb-iso-w4.tmb-iso-h4.tmb-light.tmb-overlay-text-anim.tmb-reveal-bottom.tmb-overlay-anim.tmb-content-left.tmb-text-space-reduced.tmb-image-anim.grid-cat-97.tmb-id-69092.tmb-img-ratio.tmb-content-under.tmb-media-first.tmb-no-bg
 {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

/*Change the span to block to change width. Input nbsp to content to try and remove empty space at the end of the word*/

span.portfolio-type{
    content: "\7C\a0\a0";   
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    left: 10%;
    top: 100%;
}
```

Here's the result. Positioning... working! Width... Changed significantly!:
[image]

As you see in the inspection, the width is the issue:

[image]

I have tried changing height and it works!! So clearly it's a width issue, but I'm not sure why. As this portfolio-type feature is something inside wordpress, I can only really alter is using CSS.

**Solutions I have drawn from:**

The parent/child format (so I can ensure that ALL of the same span are in the same position) comes from the solution Stephen Denken provided here: [Position an HTML element relative to its container using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104953/position-an-html-element-relative-to-its-container-using-css)

The change to block comes from: [Does height and width not apply to span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491068/does-height-and-width-not-apply-to-span)   - There are a number of topics on this subject

Then the attempt to change to nbsp comes from: [nbsp not working in CSS content tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965229/nbsp-not-working-in-css-content-tag)

Comment: Without the complete markup, this may only be guesswork. [mcve]

Comment: Do you have a live demo where we can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use inspection mode and remove width from ".tmb .t-entry-text .t-entry-text-tc .t-entry>*:not(hr):last-child", remove width from "span.portfolio-type" and change left : 10% to right : 0.

```
span.portfolio-type{
    content: "\7C\a0\a0";   
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    //width: 40px;
    //left: 10%;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
```

Please try this and let me know ^^

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the suggestion. Just for clarification, is the class name you're referring to literally spelled like ".tmb .t-entry-text .t-entry-text-tc .t-entry>*:not(hr):last-child" ? Then is it a matter of going 'width:0' for that element in the css editor? I wrote the code you've suggested in the editor and that didn't quite fix it, but that's because I haven't fully understood your first suggestions. Must be close though!

Comment: Ok so your suggestion fixed the width! Thank you very much :). I did just copy and paste that very strage class name and went 'width: 40px' and got the size I wanted. Thank!!

Comment: I just copy the class name from inspect mode ^^ You're welcome, you can also accept it as an answer~ Have a nice day