# How to use html entities in CSS content property?

Tags: html, css, entities

Good day,

I'm stuck with a problem this morning. I found out that `content` property which is nice but I can't use HTML entities in it.

More specifically, I would like to use the `&eacute;`

This is what I tried: `content: 'test with eacute \233';` but the result is `test with eacute ÿ`

I've also tried `\0233`, `\0233c`, `\233c`

I don't want to change my page's encoding.

Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: Its limitedness - doesn't accept tags, etc.- is one of the reasons why the `content` property sucks IMO. That said, using `&eacute;` should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: did you tried &copy; it will probably work, find the equivalent one for your symbol

Comment: Thanks guys but I found the answer. See below!

Comment: @Pekka — No, if you pass a `<string>` to the `content` property then it is specified that it is text and not markup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding HTML entities using CSS content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content)

Comment: **Conversion Tool** - http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmm I found that website : http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html

And it looks like the `é` (`&eacute`, `&#233`) is converted into `\00E9`

And now, `content: 'test with eacute \00E9';` works!