# Add a space (" ") after an element using :after

Tags: css

I want to add a blank space after some content, however the `content: " ";` doesn't seem to work.

This is my code:

```
h2:after {
    content: " ";
}
```

... which doesn't work, however this does:

```
h2:after {
    content: "-";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the expected outcome. Are you trying to add `padding` using `content`. It seems like it'd be impossible to tell if the space was added.

Comment: It is a weird question, you should use *padding* for adding space, no *content:after*, maybe you do not know about the difference between display:inline and display:block?

Comment: I am trying to add padding via content.

Comment: I understand that you are doing that, but why would you use something that it is less retro browser compatible, when you can use padding that has more support?

Comment: I'm adding a background to the h2 that I don't want to appear behind the text, so I use the :first-line psuedo element and set the background-color to white, however then the background image sits up against the last letter of the h2, so I used the :after psuedo element to add a space.

Comment: I found adding a space using this method was also useful when `overflow: hidden` of a block element would cut off the last few pixels of the last character of italic text. Padding wouldn't help in this case.

Comment: Padding doesn't help if you want your space to be underlined using `text-decoration: underline;` either.

Comment: Is it possible that since this question was originally asked back in 2011, things have changed in the browsers for this matter?? Because I am using (content: " ") and it works just fine (no need for encoding)...

Answer (score 211, accepted):

#### Explanation

It's worth noting that your code does insert a space

```css
h2::after {
  content: " ";
}
```

However, it's immediately removed.

From [Anonymous inline boxes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous),

> White space content that would subsequently be collapsed away
>   according to the 'white-space' property does not generate any
>   anonymous inline boxes.

And from [The 'white-space' processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model),

> If a space (U+0020) at the end of a line has 'white-space' set to
>   'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line', it is also removed.

#### Solution

So if you don't want the space to be removed, set `white-space` to `pre` or `pre-wrap`.

```css
h2 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h2.space::after {
  content: " ";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<h2>I don't have space:</h2>
<h2 class="space">I have space:</h2>
```

Do not use non-breaking spaces (U+00a0). They are supposed to prevent line breaks between words. They are not supposed to be used as non-collapsible space, that wouldn't be semantic.

Comment: It looks like `white-space` is not supported in iE11 nor Edge (see https://caniuse.com/#search=white-space). is therefore the answer by user bradley.ayers better? (I don't know, there are other aspects like semantics or line-break behavior)

Comment: Excellent solution and explanation. Thank you @Oriol!

Answer (score 681):

Turns out it needs to be specified via escaped unicode. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content) is related and contains the answer.

The solution:

```
h2:after {
    content: "\00a0";
}
```

Comment: Worth nothing that this will add a NON-BREAKING space. If you want a normal space, you need "\0020" instead of "\00A0".

Comment: Might be worth noting, too, that adding a normal space won't do anything. If you have no whitespace between the text in this, and the preceding element, this will not add one. A normal space will just collapse into itself.

Comment: @Offlein please add ` \0020` as a separate answer because some fonts, eg Font Awesome will not allow `\00A0` to display a space, and if you want a space *between* elements rather than before or after you can't use padding

Comment: How do you add space after something that is already in the content?

Comment: @vsync I had to put a space between the content and the special character. For example: "Hello \00a0".

Comment: A newer better answer uses `white-space: pre;`. Because you don't want Non-breaking chars in this case.

Comment: This solution is now deprecated, please use '\xa0'

Comment: @FrançoisDupont, do you have a resource describing this change?

Comment: Thanks but I think Oriol's answer is more comprehensive.

Comment: how could i change content value with pure javascript?

Answer (score 10):

I needed this instead of using padding because I used inline-block containers to display a series of individual events in a workflow timeline. The last event in the timeline needed no arrow after it.

Ended up with something like:

```
.transaction-tile:after {
  content: "\f105";
}

.transaction-tile:last-child:after {
  content: "\00a0";
}
```

Used fontawesome for the gt (chevron) character. For whatever reason "content: none;" was producing alignment issues on the last tile.

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
<span>first part</span>
<span>&nbsp;&#8203;</span>
<span>second part</span>
```

..."&#8203;" (or "&ZeroWidthSpace;") allows "first part" and "second part" to wrap if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code, it will add space to the content pseudo element and also keep the spacing.

```
content: "attr";
```

Answer (score -3):

There can be a problem with "\00a0" in pseudo-elements because it takes the text-decoration of its defining element, so that, for example, if the defining element is underlined, then the white space of the pseudo-element is also underlined.

The easiest way to deal with this is to define the opacity of the pseudo-element to be zero, eg:

```
element:before{
  content: "_";
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: could be a useful approach in some cases

Comment: But then when you copy the text you get the underscore copied too...

Comment: That's not a problem. Simply add `user-select:none;` to the definition of the pseudo-element. That should work in all browsers except for a few Android ones that are quirky in this respect.

Answer (score -5):

```css
element::after { 
    display: block;
    content: " ";
}
```

This worked for me.