# Add spacing between two spans

Tags: html, css

For the code below I want add spacing between "Discount" and $500. 
I **don't** want to add additional break tag. Here's the [sample on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OcaB/1/edit).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Spacing Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
        .labelReadOnlyTB {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-family: Arial;
            padding: 1px;
        }
        .labelForTextbox
        {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #000000;
        font-family: Arial;
        padding:8px 0px;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
      <tr>
         <td style="min-height:45px;vertical-align:top;">
        <span id="lblDiscount" class="labelForTextbox">Discount</span>
         <br />
        <span id="lblValue" class="labelReadOnlyTB">$500</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand you correclty you want the spans to be on separate lines, but not have to use the `<br>` tag.

`<span>` is by default an inline element. Give it a property of `display: block;`

**UPDATED with relevant code based on comment:**

```
.labelForTextbox {
  ...
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px; /** Change this value to whatever you wish **/
}
```

Comment: Add padding to one or both to space them apart even more.

Comment: I want them on separate line and so I have on <br>. Now I want to increase some spacing but don't want to add another <br/>.

Comment: Sure, I added margin-bottom in this case. That value can be whatever you want depending on your needs.

Comment: By default span is inline, not inline-block

Answer (score 32):

If you want to add spacing in html you can also use.

```
&nbsp;
```

If you put three of these before your text, it will add 3 white spaces.

for example:

```
<label>&nbsp;<span>Test</span></label>
```

Comment: I rarely use &nbsp; to layout because it takes space according to font-size, which makes it harder for layout.

Answer (score 11):

Unlike `<div>` or `<p>` (which are block-level elements), [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) is an inline element.

According to [Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties):

> `margin-top`, `margin-bottom` properties have no effect on non-replaced inline elements.

In order to use top/bottom margin properties, you need to change the element's [display type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to `block` or `inline-block` (or whatever else [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) is applicable to).

```css
span {
    display: inline-block; /* change the display type           */
    margin: 10px 0;        /* apply the needed vertical margins */
}
```

Here is the **[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/OcaB/3/edit)**

Or, Simply set `line-height` property on the table-cell instead:

```css
td { /* change the selector to select your specific td */
    line-height: 1.5; /* <-- set a line-height */
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For the second span, you can use pading-left:somevalue

Example : `<span>..</span><span style="padding-left:4px">..</span>`

Answer (score 2):

Since I see that there is a newline that puts "Discount" and "$500" on different lines I assume it will print on separate lines, and to get a little more room but not an entire new line you can use `line-height`.

In your css:

```
span#lblDiscount {
  line-height:180%
}
```

Try about 120-200% of normal line height and it will put a nice amount of spacing between your two lines.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```css
span::after {
  content: ' ';
}
```

This adds a space behind any `span` (or whatever you want). You could also combine it with `:last-child` or css sibling `+` selector to only add this for elements between.

Comment: specificly content of space didn't work (```' '``` doesn't show, adding any char in side the ' ' did work)

Comment: (there's a solution for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40963855/12056841)

Answer (score 1):

By default `<span>` is an inline element. To change this we apply the `display: block` css property. This will give the effect of a `<br>` tag without manually adding it and cluttering up our html.

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

If you wish to add spacing and not a new line you can add the `&nbsp;` [html entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) in between your 2 spans

```html
<span>Hello,</span>
&nbsp;
<span>World!</span>
```