# Creating Images with small text tags to the right in pure css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a mock up of a PSD file and i'm having trouble getting some tags at the bottom of a blog post to behave.

Here is a link to the image;

http://imageshack.com/a/img923/5718/rfVFqe.png

(I'm not allowed to post real images yet)

Here is my css code so far for it;

```
.comment {  content:url(comment.png) ; height:auto; width:auto;  }
```

and then in the html;

```
 <div class="comment"><p>comments</p></div>
```

the text does not appear at all however. I'm not sure if I can make it work this way?

Thanks all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a space (" ") after an element using :after](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467605/add-a-space-after-an-element-using-after)

Comment: I know you're adding an image, not a space, but I think the issue is just your syntax.

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to implement?
As you can render the text in another line out of the scope of div <div class="comment"></div>
<p>comments</p>

Comment: [Slightly OT] Why is this a `p` in a `div` in the first place? Looks like this should _link_ somewhere (or trigger functionality via JS perhaps), and that means it should be an `a` element to begin with. If this is a standard template of the blog system(?) you are working with, then it’s a very bad one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a similar thing for a footer of a page recently, but I had to use `img` and `p` tags.

```
<div class="comment">
<img src="svg/phone.svg" alt="Phone">
  <p>800-888-0123</p>
  <img src="svg/email.svg" alt="Email">
  <p>billy@billsplumbing.ca</p>
</div>
```

That was my markup, and my CSS looked something like:

```
div.comment *{
   display:inline-block;
   margin:0 .2rem;
}
div.comment p{
   margin-right:1rem;
}
div.comment img{
   height:25px;
   width: 25px;
}
```

I don't know if this is quite what you're looking for, but this is how I did basically what you are showing.

Comment: No problem. Glad that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `background: url(comment.png)` instead? And then add some `padding-left` to the `div`.

Code:

```css
.comment{ 
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-ui-icons-24-px/24/bubble-24-24.png') no-repeat;
  padding-left: 30px;
  height: 24px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.comment p{
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="comment"><p>Comments</p></div>
<div class="comment"><p>Comments</p></div>
<div class="comment"><p>Comments</p></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This did work, but i wanted to use 3 separate images and when I tried by making a new class for each image they did not align properly.