# Getting an empty table cell to behave like one with content

Tags: css

I am currently having an issue when a table cell contains no content, the formatting is thrown off and despite trying various techniques am unable to get it to display inline in the same way as ones with content do.

```
    <ul class="uk-wizard-progress">
        <li class="uk-complete">Welcome</li>
        <li class="uk-active"></li>
        <li>Source</li>
    </ul>
```

**Example**: http://codepen.io/nblackburn/pen/MKRVXa

I need to support both populated and unpopulated table cells but would like to tackle this with **only CSS** if it is at all possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what are you expecting it to do? It's not clear to me how this should look.

Comment: do you want box 1, 2, 3 to come in a straight line?

Comment: The goal is to get the one without content inline with the others as it currently appears out of place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `content` in `li:before` to `'\00a0'` like so:

```
li:before {
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  content: '\00a0';
  background: #dddddd;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

---

Or add `content: '\0020'` to `li:after` as Scott Marcus suggested. This will prevent an appearance of extra space before your table cell content:

```
li:after {
 content: '\0020';
 /* ... */
}
```

This is actually a best practice.

---

Source: [Add a space (" ") after an element using :after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467605/add-a-space-after-an-element-using-after)

Comment: I'd make that li::after so li's that have content won't be indented.

Comment: Thanks, i was close but was using the wrong unicode character.

Answer (score 0):

```
li::after { content:"\00a0"; }
```

Comment: This will not work. You're using wrong unicode. In CSS you must use escaped unicode.

Comment: Thanks. I still think you should make that ::after instead of adding it to the ::before so li's with content don't lead off with a space.