# CSS ellipsis breaks sentence up onto new lines

Tags: html, css, truncate, nowrap

When I have `ellipsis` on the long word, it breaks `id:` and the `[ ]` onto different lines. I can't seem to keep it all together one one line. I've tried `white-space: nowrap` and `display: inline-block`. Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/b35m449x/4/

HTML

```
<div class="container">id: [<div class="trunc">userrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</div>]</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
   display: inline-block;
   white-space: nowrap;
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 100%;
}
.trunc {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That might be happening because of the usage of another `div` in your code. If you don't need the `div` just remove it and modify the container like this:

```
.container {
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 100%;
}
```

And it will work fine.

Although if you want separate styling on that particular line (userrr...) then you might want to replace your `div` with `span` element. Note that here also you have to define your `ellipsis` and `overflow` in the `container` class.

Hope it helped a bit!

Comment: This almost works, but I need that last close bracket on the end and not going to a line also :) It kind of all needs to be on the same line.

Comment: Thank you so far! I tried putting the close bracket in a seperate div and putting floats on the two divs, but that doesnt work to bring it up next to the ...

Comment: `.container {
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
border: 1px solid black;
//width: 100%;
}
.trunc {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width:150px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}`

Make your `trunc` a span and then use this as the CSS and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudoelements to the rescue! https://jsfiddle.net/0pmzq3p4/

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
.trunc {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.trunc::before,
.trunc::after {
  white-space: pre;
}
.trunc::before {
  content: 'id: [\A\00a0';
}
.trunc::after {
  content: '\A]';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="trunc">
userrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
  </div>
</div>
```

Sources:

1. My knowledge
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17047836/915875
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5467676/915875

Answer (score 0):

Find updated fiddle, should work fine. Update in code is:

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
.trunc {
   width: 20%;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align:bottom;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

notice the additional **display: inline-block**

Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/b35m449x/4/