# How to set an empty paragraph element to the minimum height of the font-size (text)

Tags: html, css

How to set an empty paragraph element `<p>` to the height of the font size?

If a paragraph element is empty it has no height. How to set the minimum height to the text height (font-size)?

I know you can add `&nbsp;` to the element, but I want to set it purely by CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a whitespace in a pseudo-element. This should work:

```
p::after {
  content: '\00a0 '
}
```

Live demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/o96swntm/

Comment: isn't it `p::after`?

Comment: ok, but what does `\00a0 ` actually do? I guess `\0` is to write hex decimals.. but there is a space in the end?

Comment: @clarkk It's unicode of a non breaking space

Comment: you don't need to add the space in the end..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467605/add-a-space-after-an-element-using-after

Comment: @clarkk so I looked into the double colons because I realized that I always use single and never had any issue with it. So you can use both, but you need double for IE8 (and prior IE versions). See article and its comment section: https://css-tricks.com/to-double-colon-or-not-do-double-colon/

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the regular p **min-height** in a css var.

```css
:root {
  --p-height: 20px;
}

p {  
  color: white;
  background: green;
  min-height:var(--p-height);
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<p>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
p:empty {
    height: 14px;
}
```

Comment: OP asked about the height of the text, not how to set an absolute height to the element