# How can I include a HTML-encoded "content:" character in CSS?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding HTML entities using CSS content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content)

I have the following setup

CSS:

```
.header:before {
    content: "&laquo;";
}

.header:after {
    content: "&raquo;";
}
```

HTML:

```
<h3 class="header">Hello, this is some text which should be wrapped.</h3>
```

I'd simply like whatever is written in header to be wrapped in « (`&laquo;`) and » (`&raquo;`). How can I make this work in the CSS? It's currently appearing as:

> &laquo; Hello, this is some text which should be wrapped. &raquo;

rather than:

> « Hello, this is some text which should be wrapped. »

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use HTML entities in CSS, but you can use Unicode hex escapes, such as

```
span.url:before { content: "\27e8" }
span.url:after { content: "\27e9" }
```

(from one of my own stylesheets -- look up the hex codepoints for the exact characters you want yourself). Notice that unlike in some other notations, hex digits follow the backslash directly, with no intervening `u`.

Comment: Nice one! I didn't know that.

Comment: +1 and see also [CSS Syntax and basic data types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html)

Comment: But how do you get these unicode codes? It doesn't appear to be the same as the numeric code for characters. &#8595; is a down arrow, but \8595 is some Chinese character. There's a million posts just like this one. In all of them, someone says "use this code for that character" but no one explains how you get these codes.

Comment: @l008com: It's simply four hex digits giving the Unicode codepoint as a base-16 number, same as it can be looked up in the code charts in the Unicode standard. XML/HTML `&#` entities use base 10 by default, so the digits for any particular codepoint will be different from the base 16 representation.