# Can you use HTML entities in the CSS “content” property?

Tags: html, css

I would like to use HTML entities in CSS, but it shows me the `&bull;` instead.

```css
.down:before{
    content:"&bull; ";
    color:#f00;
}
```

Also, why does the above code not work in IE? it does not show the before part at all.

Comment: You want the user to see, on their screen, the `&bull;` *not* the `•` character?

Comment: i want the user to see the • and not the &bull; stuff. stackoverflow converted my html entity ;)

Comment: Which version of IE? Psuedo-elements (:before, :after) aren't supported at all at 7 and under, and only partially in 8.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/xRJmT/ looks fine here in Chrome. IE doesn't support the psuedo selector :before.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

put hex value of your bullet specail character like this

```css
div:before{
    content:"\2022";
    color:#f00;
}
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/HPrkU/1/

NOTE: after & before work in IE8

Comment: excellent, thanks! about IE: it's probably another issue on my side then. that class is attached to a li element.

Comment: If :before is not working in IE8. Then check your doctype. Put this <!DOCTYPE html> in your html

Comment: ... where "hex value" means "hexadecimal Unicode code point".

Comment: ...and in case you have only those unicode symbols itself at hand / in your clipboard, or the decimal html entities or, or, or.... [`rishida r12a unicode converter`](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/) is your greatest pal. (ever)

Answer (score 8):

I'm guessing you want the actual `•` character displayed, if so simply use the `•` character instead of `&bull;`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rmjt8/

**Edit:** I found another thread: [How can I include a HTML-encoded "content:" character in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113986/how-can-i-include-a-html-encoded-content-character-in-css)

Perhaps this will validate:

```css
.down:before{
    content:"\2022 ";
    color:#f00;
}
```

Comment: i had that before, but then it doesnt validate.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I haven't validated my css in a while ;). As long as it's cross browser and my Sass generates I'm a happy camper.

Comment: @clamp: what validation error do you get? I pasted odin’s code into http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input, and it validated just fine.

Comment: i used utf-8 encoding and it said that dot is an invalid character.

Comment: @clamp: what said that the dot is an invalid character? The W3C’s CSS validator says it’s fine.

Comment: this page here: http://validator.w3.org/ the css is inside an html file which is set to utf-8 encoding.

Comment: the error message is: The bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character Encoding. Please check both the content of the file and the character encoding indication.

Comment: @clamp: in that case, maybe you haven’t saved the file as utf-8. I’ve put up a test page [here](http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/7240520/) with the CSS in `<style>` tags in an HTML file saved as UTF-8, and it validates just fine: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pauldwaite.co.uk%2Ftest-pages%2F7240520&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: @Paul, yes that seems to be a problem. encoding of the file was ANSI.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2982/discussion-between-clamp-and-paul-d-waite)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want the user to see the `&bull;` you can simply escape that sequence, to give:

```css
.down:before{
    content:"\&bull; ";
    color:#f00;
}
```

As to why it's not visible on IE7, that's because IE doesn't support generated content or the `:before` selector.

Edited to offer that, to see the actual bullet character, you should use:

```css
.down:before{
    content:"\2022";
    color:#f00;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DG6Kb/).

Comment: nope sorry if my question was badly formulated, i want them to see the dot character. stackoverflow took the entity and converted it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape your entities:

```css
.down:before{
    content:"\&bull; ";
    color:#f00;
}
```

You cannot see it on IE because [IE doesn't support :before (not :after)](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3abefore)