# How to use hex value for bullet in CSS

Tags: css

Im trying to use hex value for bullet in CSS as mentioned here
[Can you use HTML entities in the CSS “content” property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240520/can-you-use-html-entities-in-the-css-content-property)

Note that I don't want to use `<li>` element just to show bullet

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="mybullet"/> <a href="#">Link1</a>
        </td>        
    </tr>
</table>

.mybullet
{
    content:"\2022 ";
    color:#f00;
}
```

however its not working. Here is the JsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/kq2fzb2v/

Comment: Why do you use a table? And note self-closing `span` elements won't work in HTML, only in XHTML.

Answer (score 2):

Use either `:before` or `:after`:

```
.mybullet:before
{
    content: "\2022";
    color: #f00;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.mybullet:before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="mybullet" /> <a href="#">Link1</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [`::before` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)  to your code:

```css
.mybullet::before {
    content:"\2022 ";
    color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="mybullet" /> <a href="#">Link1</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `:before` or `:after`

`<span/>` to `<span></span>`

```css
.mybullet:before
{
    content:"\2022 ";
    color:#f00;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="mybullet"> <a href="#">Link1</a></span>
        </td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Note `<span/>` will work in XHTML, so it's not necessarily wrong.

Comment: yes you are right, but it is a bad practice

Answer (score 0):

The [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property only applies to the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements:

```css
.mybullet:before {
  content: "\2022  ";
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<span class="mybullet"><a href="#">Link1</a></span>
```

Alternatively, even if you don't want to use a `li` element, you may style it as a list item:

```css
.mybullet {
  display: list-item;
  list-style: inside disc;
}
```

```html
<span class="mybullet"><a href="#">Link1</a></span>
```

Comment: Thanks All. All the answers above seems to be working..yes, I will change the self closing span..thanks for pointing out