# Vertically center dots with CSS

Tags: html, css, unicode

How can I make dots between links vertically centered with only CSS? It's possible but I can't figure out how to do it.

Expected:

[image: Facebook inline list: Unlike, Comment, Share, 1413, 70, 76, about a minute ago]

HTML

```
<label><a href="#">Like</a></label>
<label><a href="#">Comment</a></label>
<label><a href="#">Share</a></label>
<label><span>1 hour ago</span></label>​
```

CSS

```
a{ 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

label:not(:last-child):after{
    content: " . ";
}
```

Not working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZFMm/

Thanks!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use `&middot;` `·` for a dot or `&bull;` `•` for a thicker, bulleted list style dot.

For use in the `content` attribute, you'll need to escape it:

**middot:**

```
content: " \B7 ";
```

**bull:**

```
content: " \2219 ";
```

Refrences:

- [Adding HTML entities using CSS content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content)
- [24.2.1 The list of characters - Character entity references in HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/entities.html#h-24.2.1)

Comment: nice answer, thanks. but still cant get the middot right in the middle http://jsfiddle.net/4ZFMm/1/

Comment: It is in the middle, the middle of the line. You want it slightly below middle. Padding/margin/lineheight won't work here... right click  it on facebook and go to Inspect Element (Chrome), it'll give you the style for the element so you can see how they do it. I'm guessing you could do it with a bg image, too.

Comment: Actually, upon closer inspection, it's at the same level as your screenshot for me. (Chrome, Win7)

Comment: @Luccas, you fiddle displaces it. Just remove the `vertical-align` settings, and the middle dot will appear in its proper place, vertically at the middle of x-height.

Comment: How to make the bullet bigger?

Comment: I prefer the [interpunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct) `\22c5`

Comment: I want to say something. Maybe someone had the same experience. I believe I used `&bull;` in the past and in caused my computer to beep on the screen. I was trying so hard to figure out why my computer was beeping after an ajax call. When I finally got rid of the dot, it stopped beeping. Anybody have insight into that.

Answer (score 4):

Somehow these got screwed up on the live server, although they worked locally, here's what worked for me, maybe it'll help someone else:

```
.element:before {
    content: "\2022";
}
```