# Creating leading and following dots in CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to create the following effect in CSS:

[image]

Here is what I did:

```
<a class="read-more" href="#"><span>SEE MORE</span></a>
```

And for the CSS:

```
.read-more{
    display: inline-block;
}

.read-more span:before{
    content: '...';
    width: 20px;
}
.read-more span:after{
   content: '..................';
   width: 60px;
}
```

However; the dots that get displayed are in line with the base of the link. Can anybody offer a better solution or know how to bring the dots up so they are in line with the middle of the link?

Comment: Is the span element really necessary?  You should be able to achieve this look without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use \b7 instead it is the code for the middot

```
.read-more{
    display: inline-block;
}

.read-more span:before{
    content: '\b7\b7\b7';
    width: 20px;
}
.read-more span:after{
   content: '\b7\b7\b7\b7\b7\b7\b7\b7\b7\b7\b7';
   width: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a hexadecimal character code, I'd recommend using the HTML entity &middot; -- same result, greater portability. Upvoted anyway, as your answer best fits the question, but it'd be better still for the change.

Comment: @AaronMiller CSS 'content' does not accept named entities or regular numeric entities such as &#64;, but does render ASCII text and unicode.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content

Comment: @stefan Good to know; until I read your answer, I had no idea you could even specify content in CSS, and I'd have thought it would be rendered the same way any other document content would -- but I suppose, if we're going to throw out separation of concerns and have content in our CSS files anyway, there's no reason for me to assume it should be implemented in a conceptually sound fashion, is there? :) Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just add a dotted background to the link and mask it with a red background on the span... Simple and effective (as long as the background is solid)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the element to be a fixed width, you could use a dotted border for this effect.

```
<div style="padding-left:50px; border-top: 1px dotted black; width:125px;">
  <div style="display: inline-block; position: relative; top: -10px; background-color: white; padding: 0px 10px">text</div>
</div>
```

Obviously, adjust the `padding-left` and `width` to suit your layout needs.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/LDFQs/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using periods, they naturally occur where periods would occur.  One option (of many) could be to use the bullet symbol, `&bull;`, but it definitely has a heavier weight than a period.

Comment: FYI, &middot; is positioned as &bull; but has the same weight as a period.

Comment: @AaronMiller Touche... I've somehow overlooked that all these years

Comment: It's not really something you find until you go looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the "read-more" to `position:relative`, then add `position:absolute` to your `:before` and `:after` elements, specifying the `top:` and `left:`/`right:` positions to get it lined up where you want. You'll need to add some padding to the left of your text as well.