# If I have a generated icon-font as TTF, can I tell which CSS content-property belongs to which character?

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

I have a .ttf icon-font for which I have lost the guide. I am able to view the complete character set in FontBook. Is there any way to figure out which CSS content-property I can use to access each character in the font-set?

Comment: Are you trying to match the font with some sort of font book? Or is this something else

Comment: What do you mean by "which CSS content-property"? There's only one: `content`.

Comment: I think he's looking to see which icon is mapped to what character.

Comment: This might help: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/01/how-to-make-your-own-icon-webfont/

Comment: Yes, trying to work out which icon maps to which character. I have the font file, I can view it, is there any way to work out what maps to what so that I can call it using content:""?

Answer (score 3):

To complete Diodeus' answer, you have to define a new `font-face` in your stylesheet :

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'MyIconsFont';
   src: url("res/icons/MyTrueTypeFont.ttf") format("truetype");
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal
}
.my-icons {
   display: inline-block;
   font-family: 'MyIconsFont';
}
.my-icons.some-symbol:before {
   content: '\0061';  // Set the proper character index here
}
.my-icons.some-other-symbol:before {
   content: '\0064';  // Set another proper character index here 
}
```

Then use the defined styles in a dummy `<span>` or `<i>` tag:

```
<p>Here is some some symbol : <span class="my-icons some-symbol"></span> 
and some other <i class="my-icons some-other-symbol"></i></p>
```

To find out about the characters indexes, you can inspect your font in Word's Insert > Symbol > Other

Answer (score 2):

If you know the UTF-8 character code for the glyph in your font, you can specify it in the `content:` declaration in your CSS:

```
.example { content: "\203A" }
```

See also: [Adding HTML entities using CSS content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content/1412764#1412764)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io) to inspect the font and view the various notations for that glyph.

Alternatively if you convert the .ttf file to an .svg file, you can see the Unicode notations of every glyph in the file.

You can then use e.g. [an entity converter](http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html) to find out the ASCII representation of the Unicode notation, which you can use for the CSS `content:` property.