# Previewing icon font WITHOUT css

Tags: svg, icons, truetype, icon-fonts

I need to view an icon.ttf (svg,woff,eot,whatever) font file. I do NOT want to create CSS to do this. There are hundreds of icons and I need to look at them quickly. Is there anything I can use to open the font file?

The only responses are along this vein: [If I have a generated icon-font as TTF, can I tell which CSS content-property belongs to which character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524660/if-i-have-a-generated-icon-font-as-ttf-can-i-tell-which-css-content-property-be) and include CSS - that is NOT what I am looking for. I want to preview the file NOT through manual entry using CSS (or SASS, etc).

I am assuming this cannot be done since I havent found a decent answer. If you have the knowledge for how to preview an icon font, please share!!

Comment: Do you have access to the font locally?

Comment: Are you talking about a programmatic way of viewing an icon file? Because otherwise, this doesn't seem to be on-topic according to  [help/on-topic].

Comment: I don't know what you mean by programmatic. In windows or Mac you can click on a font and see how it looks. With icons it just shows the quick brown fox text as a San serif. I want to see it as icons.

Comment: A friend is telling me that if there is no answer to this that I should put it on super users. But I wasn't sure if there was actually no programmatic answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Character Map tool in Windows. Just select the icon font and you can preview the entire list as well as the corresponding css codes.