# Add HTML tag inside CSS Content property

Tags: css, css-content

I'm looking for a way to add an HTML tag for CSS content property inside `:after` and `:before`.

Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190396/863380) which only discusses adding symbols like `<`. What I'm trying to add is something like:

```
.breadcrumbs li a:before {
    content: '<i class="icon"></i>';
}
```

Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: An italic element with no content and a class of icon? Yuck.

Comment: Why not just add the icon inside the `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is impossible. You cannot generate markup from CSS.

It should also be unnecessary - stick your background image / icon font / whatever in the generated pseudo-element you have already.

Comment: The only way I can image is with Javascript (/jQuery). Pure CSS, impossible!

Comment: @MuhammadReda — Use the code you are already using for your `i` element.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you want,

To put an image to the left of your breadcrumb li links:

```
.breadcrumbs li a::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url('/img/breadcrumb-icon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left; /*icon on the left*/
    margin: 0 6px 0 0; /*margin on the right so there is a gap between your icon and link*/
}
```

If you want it on the other side try `float:right;margin: 0 0 0 6px;` or use `::after` should get you part of the way