# Is it possible to use (multiple) font styles within CSS `content`?

Tags: html, css, css-content

I've got a CSS element set up to insert some content, via:

```
.foo:after {
  content: "Bold, italics";
}
```

I'd like the word "Bold" to be rendered in a bold font-weight and the word "italics" to be rendered in an italics font-style. I know it's possible to add lines:

```
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italics;
```

But this will make both words bold and italics. If I [could](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505093/css-content-property-is-it-possible-to-insert-html-instead-of-text) use html elements inside the content field I would put something like:

```
content: "<strong>Bold</strong>, <em>italics</em>"
```

But alas that's not possible.

Is there another way to achieve this effect? Ideally without invoking javascript and purely using html/css.

Comment: I don't think so (hack?), but I'll be interested to see if someone can work that out.

Comment: Seems to be impossible, according to the answers [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505093/css-content-property-is-it-possible-to-insert-html-instead-of-text) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511499/add-html-tag-inside-css-content-property). It's probably will be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: other than using `.foo:before { font-weight: bold; }` and then `.foo:after { font-style: italics; }` I would also love to know this one too. Seems like doing only one psuedo w/o changing the markup isn't possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's mentioned above, but unless you add a `:before` and `:after` not too sure how it can be accomplished without JS..

```
.foo {
  float: left;
}
.foo:after {
  content: "Bold, ";
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: .5em;
  display: block;
}
.foo:before {
  content: 'Italic';
  font-style: italic;
  float: right;
  margin-left: .5em;
  display: block;
}
```

It also contains floats everywhere, but, hey! it works:)

Check it here: http://codepen.io/achoukah/pen/gpBopd

**EDIT:**

Heres the same, but with flex-box:

```
.foo {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
}
.foo:before {
  content: "Bold, ";
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: .5em;
  order: 1;

}
.foo:after {
  content: 'Italic';
  font-style: italic;
  margin-left: .5em;
  order: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do have **other** pseudo elements than 'after'/'before', like **first-line** or **first-letter**, which, with some imagination, maybe you could use on your particularly case:  
[w3schools Pseudo-elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)  
But '*inside*' those first 2 I think you can not do nothing more, like @s0rfi949 pointed out.