# How can I add a FontAwesome character to the beginning of all blockquotes?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am using FontAwesome. Right now I have a blockquote which has an image in front of it that shows its a quote mark.

```
blockquote {
    background-image: url("./styles/roman/imageset/forum/quote.gif");
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: 6px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-color: #dbdbce;
    border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    margin: 0.5em 1px 0 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

FontAwesome has a quote mark in their font, I was wondering if there is a way to change it from currently being a background to just showing the character. I did not know if using content and a font type would work.

**Example**

["] This is a quote for whatever magazine.

where ["] is currently the quote image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the CSS pseudo-selector `::before`.

For your example you would use:

```
blockquote::before {
  content: '\"';
}
```

For further reference, [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before).

If you wish to include the icon from the FontAwesome library, you can try with the following:

```
blockquote::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f10d'; /*quote left icon*/
}
```

Comment: You are the only person that answered the question.  All other answers are incorrect.

Comment: Use `font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free'` for Font Awesome 5

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `::before` pseudo-element with `content: open-quote` to insert an opening quote, and an `::after` one with `content: no-close-quote` to decrement the quote nesting level without displaying any quote.

If you want to customize the quotation marks, use the `quotes` property. According to [A list of Font Awesome icons](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/), `fa-quote-left` is `\f10d` and `fa-quote-right` is `\f10e`.

Finally, to display that character using in the appropriate font, use `font-family: FontAwesome`.

```css
blockquote { quotes: "\f10d" "\f10e" '“' '”' "‘" "’"; }
blockquote::before { content: open-quote; font-family: FontAwesome; }
blockquote::after  { content: no-close-quote; }
```

```html
<link href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<blockquote>
  Hello world!
  <blockquote>Foo bar<blockquote>Baz</blockquote></blockquote>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: As the question was specifically asking about Font Awesome, this is not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511499/add-html-tag-inside-css-content-property

Comment: @Iscariot You can't insert HTML with CSS, but I think Font Awesome inserts a custom font and you might be able to set the appropriate `font-family` to use that font. I don't have much idea about Font Awesome, thought.

Comment: @TylerH I meant you can't insert HTML elements. With `content` you can only generate text or external resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something like the CSS [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo selector:

```
blockquote::before {
   content: "\"";
}
```

That will insert a single quote mark before the blockquote element. (Note the escape mark.)

If you wanted to display an image, you might use this:

```
blockquote::before {
   content: '<img src="./styles/roman/imageset/forum/quote.gif" class="quotemark"/>';
}

img.quotemark {
  /* Style the image here. */
}
```

Comment: As the question was specifically asking about Font Awesome, this is not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511499/add-html-tag-inside-css-content-property