# How do I style Paged media elements

Tags: css, css-paged-media

Neither google nor the @Page [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html) nor [this link](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/) has any info on this.

I have the following code to show page numbers in a footer on the right of the page of the pdf I generate from html :

```
@page {
  @bottom-right {
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
  }
}
```

This happily prints `Page A of X`. How do I style A and X ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't using CSS alone.  In order to style `A` and `X` separately from the rest of the text, you need to insert elements to wrap `A` and `X` like:

```
 Page <span class="a">A</span> of <span class="b">B</span>
```

However, you [cannot insert tags using the CSS `content` tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511499/add-html-tag-inside-css-content-property)  Thus in order to accomplish this, you should create a footer element ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document)) in HTML, and style it accordingly.  For example:

```
<div class="footer">
    Page <span class="a">A</span> of <span class="b">B</span>
</div>


@media screen {
  div.footer {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  div.footer {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     padding-right: 30px;
  }

  div.footer a{
     // STYLING FOR A GOES HERE
  }
}
```