# CSS-only multimedia tooltip using attr()

Tags: css

The CSS3 `attr()` function is useful, elegant, concise.

This particular [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dvo4/2b5ny9t8/2/) demonstrates this straightforwardness for a CSS_only tooltip.
However, I have never managed to generate the content of the tooltip

```
<div tooltip="straight text [...]">
```

as anything other than straight text. Inserting an image tag (*second tooltip example*) will generate the litteral textual representation of the image tag.

Is there any way to include both image and text in an `attr()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS trick relies on changing the content of the pseudo class `:before`

Adding HTML content there will not work. See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22511546/11854340

Comment: Also if you want to add image, add it like a background. I think this works fine.