# CSS put html entity as content

Tags: html, css, html-entities, html-encode, html-escape-characters

Using the css `content` property, I am trying to make put an HTML entity after an element.

**Here is my HTML**:

```
<table id="tic" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="5" bordercolor="black" bordercolorlight="gray" bgcolor="white">
    <tr>
        <td width="55" height="55" class="x"></td>
        <td width="55" height="55" class="o"></td>
        <td width="55" height="55" class="x"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="55" height="55" class="o"></td>
        <td width="55" height="55" class="x"></td>
        <td width="55" height="55" class="o"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="55" height="55" class="x"></td>
        <td width="55" height="55" class="o"></td>
        <td width="55" height="55" class="x"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**And my CSS**:

```
table{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2em;
    font-weight:bold;
}
td.o:after{
    content:"&#9675;";
    font-weight:bold;
}
td.x:after{
    content:"&#x2716;"
}
```

Unfortunately, instead of getting the ○ character and the ✖ character, I get the entity names.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Progo/Dp78c/)**

**How can I fix this**? Thanks!

Comment: http://unicode-table.com/ and use the answer from @dejakob for the code.  Go nuts

Comment: you have to use the escaped unicode.. check below stackoverflow.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS isn't HTML. You can't use HTML entities in it.

Use the literal character (`✖`) or a CSS [unicode escape](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-string) instead.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Unfortunately I can't accept it for eight more minutes… :(

Comment: 8 minutes have past...

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the escaped unicode :

Like

```
td.o:after {
    content:"\00a2"; 
}
td.x:after {
    content:"\00a4"; 
}
```

More info on : http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
td.o:after{
    content:"\9675";
    font-weight:bold;
}
td.x:after{
    content:"\2716"
}
```

For the first one, it gives another symbol, so please check if you used the right code for it...

http://jsfiddle.net/7XXbK/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dp78c/4/

```
table{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2em;
    font-weight:bold;
}
td.o:after{
    content:"\25CB";
    font-weight:bold;
} 
td.x:after{
    content:"\2716";
}
```

You need to use the unicode escaped character instead. You can use this tool to translate for you as well if you need to:

http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html