# sass not parsing bullet point/HTML code correctly

Tags: css, sass

Hi have this in my sass:

```
   &:before {
                content:"·";
                font-size:120px;
            }
```

but in the CSS it's being parsed as `┬À`. Is it to do with codification or something? What do I need to do to adjust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the escaped unicode instead:

```
&:before
{
    content: '\00B7';
    font-size: 120px;
}
```

More information:

- http://css-tricks.com/css-content/
- [Adding HTML entities using CSS content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content)

Comment: that gives me the square bullet how do I get the round one, thanks?