# Add whitepaces with ::before selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have tried this but it didn't work:

```css
.stackoverflow::before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f16c ";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a class="stack-link stackoverflow" href="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>
```

Can we add whitespace(s) with `::before` selector and `content` property like that?

Comment: Could it be added as a margin right?

Comment: That's weird... If I add 1 more space, or replace the icon itself with another character, it works...

Comment: ^ This seemingly strange behavior is addressed over there. The first space after an escape sequence is the delimiter to define it has ended.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Thank you for the reference. That's what I really want to learn about :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can add whitespace like this `content: "\f16c  \00a0";`

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4k4pdq0/)

`\00a0` is hex code for a non-breaking space,used in `content` property. [More Info](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Can you explain the significance of this code?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Edited the answer man :)

Comment: Better. You wouldn't happen to know why 2 regular spaces and `"A "` with just 1 space works, but `"\f16c ";` doesn't would you? I'm finding this rather bizarre.

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm :)

Comment: As i mentioned in the answer, \00a0 is the hex code for non-breaking space used in the content property. We cant directy use &nbsp; in content property. So for that reason we are using the hex code. More Info in http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/

Comment: Ah, I've located the root cause for this seeming strange behavior. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content

Answer (score 1):

Yep, use `\a0` it's `&nbsp;` or non-breaking space.

```css
.stackoverflow::before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f16c\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0";
}
```

```html
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <a class="stack-link stackoverflow" href="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the intention is to add spacing after the icon.