# CSS prevent element from snapping into place after transition ease-in-out

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some divs on my page which drop down from above when selected from the menu. This works as intended. However, when the element is in its final location and the viewport has shrunk to a mobile friendly view, activating the drop down menu causes the element to first follow the menu's movement down (good and OK), but after the menu animation has finished the element snaps back up to a different position. A cool effect if intended, but not something I wish to have. The effect (after first selecting from menu) can be seen here:

[image: Janky movements]

I am using unedited bootstrap.css 3.3.6 with custom CSS found in this [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/NkHPM0u9V2)

Press the mobile icon in the fiddle editor to open it in small screen window.

To reproduce: Run fiddle, open any item from menu, make sure hamburger menu is present, open and close menu while content is visible.

Here is the CSS if you do not wish to or cannot view the fiddle:

```
    html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.navbar li { 
  color: slategrey;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.navbar-collapse#myNavbar {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.collapsing {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

.collapse {
  border: 0;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu::after{
  border:0;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-collapse {
  border: 0;
}

.navbar.navbar-default {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: slategrey;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#name {
  color: white;
}

#center {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

#kyrrContainer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

.panel {
  min-width: 80%;
  height: 75%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-top: -300%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  z-index: 11;
  -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  /*animation-name: colorTransition;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;*/
}

.panel:target {
  margin-top: 0%;
  background-color: #ffcb00; 
}

.transitionedText p {
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 10px;
      line-height: 24px;
      color: #fff;
      display: inline-block;
      background: black;
      margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    }

    .transitionedText li {
      list-style-type: hiragana;
    }

    .content h2 {
      font-size: 110px;
      padding: 10px 0px 20px 0px;
      margin-top: 52px;
      color: #fff;
      color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
```

And the HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><div id="kyrrContainer"><div id="overlay"><p id="name">K B</p></div></div></a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right">
        <li><a href="#music"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span> Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#web"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span> Web</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="center">
  <div id="home" class="content">
        <div id="kyrrContainer">
            <div id="overlay"><p id="name">M Y  <br> C O O L <br> P A G E</p></div>
            <div id="slow"></div>
            <div id="fast"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="music" class="panel">
  <div class="content transitionedText">
    <p>M Y &nbsp;&nbsp; C O N T E N T</p>
    <ul>
      <li><p>Hello</p></li>
      <li><p>World!</p></li>
      <li><p>wehhhhhhh</p></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="web" class="panel">
  <div class="content transitionedText">
    <p>P L E A S E &nbsp;&nbsp; L O O K</p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://www.example.com/" target="_blank"><p>example.com</p></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help or pointers is greatly appriciated!

Comment: unrelated question: how did you made the gif?

Comment: Chrome extension Gif Cat @stig-js

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

use CSS :before and :after to enter new positions.

Answer (score 0):

Using André's suggestion of ::before and ::after, I did this:

```
.collapse::after {
  content: " \0000a0 ";
}
```

Seems "hacky", but produces a desired result. It adds a

```
&nbsp;
```

after the menu.

With help from [this question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content)

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/XB94WBmvSh)

Answer (score 0):

try content: "" to see if that works better. Also if you are satisfied with the answer would you kindly tick your question as answered. Thx

Comment: I tried content: "" as well as content: " "  and those did not work. Your answer was a good hint in the right direction, but in no way a complete answer to the problem and cannot be accepted as such.

Comment: No that is fine I just mean if you are satisfied... you know the drill :)