# what does content : '' mean in pseudo class?

Tags: css, html, pseudo-class

what does "{content : ' '}" mean in css ***pseudo class*** ?

i'm still wondering everyday, what does that mean ?

Anybody can help me please

Comment: google is your friend :)

Comment: *content - CSS | MDN* : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: Akbar, you should give an example when you ask this type of question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding HTML entities using CSS content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content)

Answer (score 0):

In css, you use content to just set the content (or inner html)

This is a clear example from [mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)

HTML

```
<a href="http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/">Mozilla Home Page</a>
```

CSS

```
a::before {
  content: url("https://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/favicon.ico") " MOZILLA: ";
  font: x-small Arial, sans-serif;
  color: gray;
}
```