# How to position this <ul> under <h4>?

Tags: html, css

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 30vh;
  background-color: #a44949;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.footer-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <h4>Kontakt</h4>
  <ul class="footer-list">
    <li>Mobilni: 062/329-077</li>
  </ul>
  <h4>Podaci</h4>
  <ul class="footer-list">
    <li>PIB: 112295370</li>
    <li>Matični broj: 66007057</li>
  </ul>
  <h4>Lokacija</h4>
  <ul class="footer-list">
    <li>Oslobođenja 32c, Rumenka</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How it looks like:
[image: click]

I want those **ul** elements placed under the **h4** , how do I do it? did I mess something up or? I will add more stuff to it, I planned to add a google map for the location too

EDIT: Another issue

So, I've solved my first and second issue, now here comes the third. Added a map thumbnail, h4 positioning kinda got messed up as you can see here

enter code herehttps://jsfiddle.net/sushmee/nz1txweh/1/

EDIT2: And another issue

How to fix [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fApl2.png) div with p and text in it, goes under footer instead of expanding the body? I have another line of text, you just cant see it

Comment: You left `flex-direction` of the container at the default `row`, so all items will by laid out next to each other. But switching it to `column` won’t achieve what you want here either. You should start by wrapping each H4 and its corresponding UL into an additional element.

Comment: Awesome, that solved it! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 30vh;
  background-color: #a44949;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div>
  <h4>Kontakt</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>Mobilni: 062/329-077</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
  <h4>Podaci</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>PIB: 112295370</li>
    <li>Matični broj: 66007057</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
  <h4>Lokacija</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>Oslobođenja 32c, Rumenka</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That solved it, awesome! Now, one more issue. How do I place li Maticni broj under PIB?
Edit: Solved it, changed display from flex to block

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options, the first is to stay with CSS flex layout, and wrap the `<h4>` elements into a 'wrapping' element with its associated `<ul>`, and the second – as you want to align across columns and rows – is to use CSS grid layout.

To show the first option, because you're effectively showing a navigation list with associated lists, we wrap the `<h4>` elements along with its associated `<ul>` in a wrapper `<li>` element which, of course, requires either a `<ul>` or `<ol>` parent.

I've effectively stripped out all of the styling, so you will need to reintroduce the styles required to position the `.footer` element, but this should be enough to show you how to visually align the elements:

```css
/* a basic reset so that elements are sized, and
   spaced, consistently: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* removing all list-markers from the <ul> elements
   within the .footer element: */
.footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.footer-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* to show how a marker could be added back to the
   descendant <li> elements that follow the <h4>:  */
h4 + ul ::marker {
  /* a right guillemet, using unicode: */
  content: '\00BB';
  width: 0.5em;
}

h4 + ul li {
  /* making space for the marker: */
  margin-left: 0.6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <!-- this element serves to wrap each of the content 'columns'
       in <li> elements in order that flex-box layout can
       position the <h4> along with its associated list of
       links; the class-name is used for ease-of-selecting: -->
  <ul class="footer-list">
    <li>
      <h4>Kontakt</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>Mobilni: 062/329-077</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <h4>Podaci</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>PIB: 112295370</li>
        <li>Matični broj: 66007057</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>Lokacija</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>Oslobođenja 32c, Rumenka</li>
      </ul>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ur0b7ctw/).

The second option, as mentioned above, is to use CSS grid, though because this does not wrap the relevant `<h4>` and `<ul>` within the same parent, this is somewhat brittle, but can be used:

```css
/* a basic reset so that elements are sized, and
   spaced, consistently: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* removing all list-markers from the <ul> elements
   within the .footer element: */
.footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.footer {
  display: grid;
  /* because we're positioning the elements in pairs,
     one h4 to one ul, we use two rows and direct the
     layout to place elements in column direction
     instead of rows: */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, min-content);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
      <h4>Kontakt</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>Mobilni: 062/329-077</li>
      </ul>
      
      <h4>Podaci</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>PIB: 112295370</li>
        <li>Matični broj: 66007057</li>
      </ul>
      <h4>Lokacija</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>Oslobođenja 32c, Rumenka</li>
      </ul>
      
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ur0b7ctw/1/).

References:

- [Adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`grid-auto-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`grid-template-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows).
- [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
- [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type).
- [`::marker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker).
- [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).

Bibliography:

- "[Adding HTML entities using CSS content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190396/82548)."
- "[Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)."
- "[CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)."
- "[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)."
- "[A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)."

Comment: Solved my issue, but holy dang, you did your job :) But I have another issue, I posted what's wrong