# React Replacing Special Characters in CSS `content`

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, pseudo-element

### Issue

When loading my React webapp, sometimes special characters (e.g. `⋮`) are replaced with strings of other characters (e.g. `â‹®`). The special characters appear correctly *most* of the time, but when this bug occurs all the below-listed special characters fail to display correctly. I am unable to intentionally replicate the issue.

### Code Sample

The special characters are all within the CSS styles:

```
.someElement:before {
  content: "⋮";
}
```

### Example Characters

Here are the unintended replacements that are occurring with seemingly random frequency:

| Intended Character | Characters that Appear |
| --- | --- |
| `⋮` | `â‹®` |
| `▾` | `â–¾` |
| `✔` | `âœ”` |

Comment: ⋮ = content: '\22EE', ▾ = content: '\25BE', ✔ = content: '\2714'

Comment: for other special characters refer to this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_entities.asp

Comment: It is unclear why the characters are appearing sometimes but not all the time, however using the code rather than the glyph in the CSS appears to be working initially.

Comment: This may be a React-specific issue, but it seems to be related to this CSS entities question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using special characters in CSS you must add their `CSS entity` instead of only character

in your case you want to add `⋮` to css which its entity code is \22EE

```
.someElement:before {
  content: "\22EE";
}
```

for more entity codes check out here

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_entities.asp